# execCommand backColor and hilitecolor not working on chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, execcommand

I have got a contenteditable div element and a button as such

```
<button onClick="backColor();">Change BC</button>
<div contenteditable="true"></div>
```

inside the body of my index.html file. My JS file looks like this

```
function backColor() {
    document.execCommand("hiliteColor", false, "#3399ff");
}
```

but the text I am writing and the text I have highlighted does not get any color change what so ever. I am using chrome "version 78. something". I have also tried changing "hiliteColor" to "backColor" and "backcolor" as well as "hilitecolor" and "color". I have also tried changing "#3399ff" to "red" and "ff00ff". Still, no change in color what so ever. Why am I not seeing any color change?

Edit:
I have now got the following code (STILL NOT WORKING BTW)

```
function backColor(h_color) {
    document.execCommand("styleWithCSS", true, null);
    alert(document.queryCommandState("styleWithCss")); // returns true only if the above execCommand function is executed. Still no change
    document.execCommand("hiliteColor", false, "#3399ff");
    doc.focus();
}
```

Comment: Is there some information that I have not included that someone would like to know? Do I need to clarify anything?

Comment: [It works here...](https://jsfiddle.net/tfx8jeay/)

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I have a button that opens a menu using javascript and the actual thing being pressed in order to set back color to text was:

```
<div onClick="backColor();" style="width: 25px; height:25px; background-color: red;"></div>
```

Everything but execCommand works perfectly inside the javascript when a div is pressed. If I change the div to a button, still the same function and everything, the document.execCommand works again.